# A Matlab surf like plot with a colormap in mathematica?

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I would like to ask the community for help in creating a Matlab-like 3D surf plot with a colormap but in Mathematica. To make the question more specific lets say that we have a set of numbers in 3D space and to each point some function value c is asigned:

```
{{x1,y1,z1,c1},{x2,y2,z2,c2},...,{xN,yN,zN,cN}}
```

These points lay on a surface in 3D e.g. a sphere. Now in matlab if these points are properly represented as matrixes `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `C` we can simpliy plot this surface with

```
k = 5;
n = 2^k-1;
[x,y,z] = sphere(n);
c = magic(2^k);
surf(x,y,z,c);
colormap gray
axis equal
```

What is important here are the function values which can be read of the plot thanks to the colorbar.

Now the question to the community is:

Can we produce such a plot in Mathematica (with a colorbar - this is the important part)???

I searched for a solution on the web without luck. I looked at things like `ListPlot3D`, `ListSurfacePlot3D`, `ListPointPlot3D` but to these functions you can only pass a surface without the corresponding point values (unless there is something I don't understand).

Does anyone know a solution, a way to create such plots in Wolfram Mathematica?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ColorFunction` to specify, well, the color function :

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] Cos[f], Sin[t] Sin[f], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, Pi}, {f, 0, 2 Pi} , 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t, f}, RGBColor[z]]]
```

[image: plot]

Another way is to use textures; I will use the data you generated with the other software.

```
{x, y, z, c} = Import["/tmp/sphere.mat"];
```

The texture we want to apply is `c` (actually rotated 90 degrees)

```
ArrayPlot[c]
```

[image: texture]

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] Cos[f], Sin[t] Sin[f], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, Pi}, {f, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Texture[ Rotate[ArrayPlot[c], Pi/2]], Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: sphereM]

Comment: Thank you b.gatessucks for the reply and an interesting solution. Though I must say that the Matlab solution is much more convenient (at least for me). Thanks again!

Comment: I must say I took the texture example for granted. A closer look at it shows that it doesn't solve the problem and in fact it might be misleading. The problem with it is that the ArrayPlot[c] figure contains the black frame which is also mapped on the sphere. If you rotate the last figure of this answer around the z axis by 180 deg a sewing or stitching effect is visible. This is even more evident for a simple c={{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3}}. A solution to thiss would be to turn of the balck frame or create a figure in a different program (but this creates more complications).